# How to post request to my backend server with long string argument by Graphql

Tags: python, django, api, graphql

I wanna post a request from my website to back-end (django) by GraphQL. Here is my GraphQL request. Probably because the argument is too long, the request cannot reach my server but there is no error threw by Graphql which still show the status "200". How can I solve this problem?

```
{
  sendMail(mailList: "abv@gmail.com abv@gmail.com abv@gmail.com abv@gmail.com ........... (1000 mail here )", content: "testing") {
    data {
      counter
    }
    ok
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you're getting a 200, the request is reaching the server fine. GraphQL itself wouldn't limit the size of the string. It may be related to whatever database you're using. What is the exact response you receive from the server? Is there an `errors` array included in the response?

Comment: @DanielRearden oh yea, I found that its not GraphQL's problem, actually when the request go to my backend server, it will call another rest api to my another Django server. The error is  "POST /graphql HTTP/1.0" 200 -
b'<html>\r\n<head><title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>414 Request-URI Too Large</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n' How can I solve this problem?